# How can I concatenate a string using a condition?

Tags: javascript, xml

My XML is below. I have two possible tag names within the `<messageset>` tag. It has to be either `<message>` or `<time>`. Depending on the tag within I need to set a different content to a `div` element on the page.

How can I use an if/else condition here?

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("messageset");
for (...) {
    //some codes
    var msg = x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].tagName;
    var row = "<div>" +
    if (msg == "message") {
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
    else {
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    }
    +"</div>"
}
```

**XML file:**

```
<messages>
    <messageset>
        <name>torje</name>
        <time>1533904445</time>
        <message>A hi fyi bk MLS egg FG ch bhi CDG jk IC</message>
    </messageset>
    <messageset>
        <name>torje</name>
        <time>1533905156</time>
        <link>msgfh.gif</link>
    </messageset>
</messages>
```

**Edit:** Firefox says syntax error `if (msg == "message")...`. I dont think this is right place to use a condition.

**Edit**
 after using the inline code it is still not working may be my condition is incorrect,  if `<messagset>` has  tag the show , `<name> + <message>`  if it has  tag then show `<name> + <message>` inside row variable

```
(msgtg != null ? x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue  : x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) +
```

Comment: Either `<message>` or `<time>` or rather `<message>` or _`<link>`_? Have you tried `else if(msg == "link")` instead of just `else`?

Comment: Surely `.getElementsByTagName("message")[0].tagName` will always be `"message"`?

Comment: @Xufox sorry typo,  i dont know this is my approch any other condition i can use so it could show either message or link

Comment: closing div should be `'</div>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var getMessage = function(messageSetNode) {
  var wrapInDiv = function(msg) {
    return "<div>" + msg + "</div>";
  }
  var messageNode = messageSetNode.getElementsByTagName("message")[0]; 
  if(messageNode) {
    return wrapInDiv(messageNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  }
  return wrapInDiv(messageSetNode.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("messageset");

for(...) {
  var row = getMessage(x[i]);
}
```

The idea here is to separate the concerns, in one function i select the message (with his own scope), and i just call that inside the loop, also i added a function inside the getMessage function to wrap everything in a div.

But the function is not safe if there's no link tag or childNodes, i suppose you are aware of that and you don't want a silent error there.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

An if/else condition does not return a value on its own, so you cannot use it for string concatenation. So this is not valid JavaScript (thence the Firefox error message in the JavaSript console):

```
var row = "<div>" +
if (msg == "message") {
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
else {
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
}
+"</div>"
```

However, you could do this:

```
var row = "<div>" + (msg == "message" ? x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue : x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + "</div>";
```

But I would prefer the following syntax, as it is more readable:

```
var row = "<div>";
if (msg == "message") {
    row += x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
else {
    row += x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
row += "</div>";
```

Comment: oh thanks but not working still may  i have edited , actually if `<messagset>` has <message> tag the show , `<name> + <message>`  if it has <link> tag then show `<name> + <message>` inside row variable

Comment: @Anjali: Basically this line does not make sense: `var msg  = x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].tagName;` as you are asking here for the `message` tags within the `messageset` tag. Later you have a condition for the tag name. But it can only be `message`. The else is never reached.